# How to change the JQuery Sortable Helper Dynamically based on the element it hovered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to change the Helper based on the element it is currently hovered. I am trying to find the hovered element but i am not getting. How to get the Hovered element ?

```
$('.sortableTable tbody').sortable({
connectWith: ".sortableTable tr",
items: "tr:not(.disabled)",
helper: function (event, element) {
    return $('<div class="hoverCard">Valid</div>')
},
sort: function (event, ui) {
    console.log($(ui.item).data().sortableItem.currentItem.context.innerHTML);
    ui.helper = $('<div class="hoverCard">Testing</div>');

}
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by the hovered element? The item that's currently being dragged?

Comment: No, the item which is below the dragged item.

Comment: Can you also post HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem

// X & Y are the current cursor position.

// dropKeys are the Draggable elements(Elements which are allowed to move).

// It checks X & Y is on the draggable element or not, If "Yes - return true" else "return false"

```
function isValidPosition (x, y, dropKeys) {
 var isValid = false;
 var dropAreaOffset, dropAreaWidth, dropAreaHeight;
 $.each(dropKeys, function (index, item) {
    dropAreaOffset = $(item).offset();
    dropAreaWidth = $(item).width();
    dropAreaHeight = $(item).height() + 3;

    if (dropAreaOffset && dropAreaHeight && dropAreaWidth) {
        if (x > dropAreaOffset.left && x < (dropAreaOffset.left + dropAreaWidth)) {
            if (y > dropAreaOffset.top && y < (dropAreaOffset.top + dropAreaHeight)) {
                isValid = true;
                return false;  // break the $.each() loop.
            }
        }

    }
});

return isValid;
```

};

// Based on the return value i am changing the Helper text :

```
if (isValidPosition(event.pageX, event.pageY, items)) {
    $('.floaty').addClass('drop-valid').removeClass('drop-not-valid');
}
else {
    $('.floaty').addClass('drop-not-valid').removeClass('drop-valid');
}
```